# ¿Cómo hago para que un Label se muestre en pantalla después o encima de otro Label? en VBA word

Tags: visual-basic

O simplemente hacer que en un Label pueda mostrar varias peticiones, o sea, me refiero a que con un Label hago una pregunta y el usuario la responde, luego de obtener una respuesta pues la pregunta del Label se cambia por otra o por cualquier otra cosa que desee agregar.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Es que quiero hacer un formulario, entonces en la pantalla del formulario al inicio se mostrará una pregunta, pero luego se hacen otras preguntas dependiendo de lo que responda la persona, obviamente no las puedo poner de una cuando se abre el formulario porque sólo se deben mostrar dependiendo de la respuesta, sooo, no sé cómo hacer para que esas preguntas aparescan en la pantalla del formulario después de la pregunta inicial...